# Detect how much of a canvas element is filled in HTML5

Tags: html5-canvas, getimagedata

I just started with HTML5, and I have a paint program where a user can fill in the canvas by clicking the mouse button and dragging the cursor around like a pen. I want to be able to figure out what percentage of the canvas is currently filled with the pen. How could I do this? [Here's my current code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/3797327) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the raw pixel values of the `<canvas>` using getImageData() call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29

Then you loop through this pixel data in a Javascript loop and count all pixels which are not of the background color.

The percent of filled in canvas is

```
 completed = filledInPixels / (canvas.width * canvas.height)
```

Note that `getImageData()` call is extremely slow and you might want to call it only like once in a second.

Comment: how to get the `filledInPixels` ?